# PHP on Facebook Fan Page - is it possible?

Tags: php, sql, database, facebook

I am setting up a competition on a Facebook page - i.e. a Facebook Tab Page.

When a fan "likes" the page they are shown a HTML form where they submit their name and email.
I have explored using an Awebber form but this page will/should exceed their max allowed subscriptions per month.

So basically I will set up my own SQL DB and attempt to connect to it from the Facebook page  and send the entrant's details to it.

Does Facebook allow you to do this through PHP? Or is there any easier alternative I should try?

Thanks Guys

Comment: Does anybody have know of any more tutorials for this please? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Facebook Canvas and Tab pages are simply iframes pointing to a page on your server, so yes, you can do normal PHP stuff there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this using Facebook's iFrames. They used to use FBML, but that is now deprecated. [See this post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/462/) for more details and great examples on how to get started.

Essentially, you create a page on your own website that is no wider than 520px wide, and point your Facebook page tab to that.